# Adding a class to a <ul> in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to a add a HTML .class to an unordered list item using Ruby or possibly a rails helper method?

Basically I'm just iterating through a todo model

```
<ul>
<% @todos.each do |todo| %>
  <li><%= todo.task %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class="third" to the third list item so the HTML output would look like

```
<ul>
  <li>Task 1</li>
  <li>Task 2</li>
  <li class="third">Task 3</li>
<ul>
```

I was using jQuery to add the class but I wanted a better way of doing this instead of relaying on javascript.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it using [each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) (the index starts at zero):

```
<ul>
<% @todos.each_with_index do |todo,index| %>
  <li<%= ' class="third"' if index == 2 %>><%= todo.task %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: If the class has to be added to **every** 3rd `li`, `if (index % 3) == 0` would make more sense

Comment: @zsquare True, but that wasn't the question :)

Comment: You are both gems. Thanks for helping me out and being nice.